# Custom Malloc() Function :: What Does this Syntax Mean?

Tags: c, syntax, malloc, function-prototypes, ndpi

I am writing a C program with the nDPI library, [available here](https://github.com/ntop/nDPI). (Coding on a Ubuntu machine, GCC compiler, nDPI version 3.2)  nDPI is used to inspect network traffic. The code uses a lot of different structs to represent network stuff, like network flows, network protocols, network hosts, and so on.

So I think that if you want to create these structs, you must use the library's custom `malloc()` and `free()` functions, which makes sense. But I'm having a hard time understanding the function prototypes. Here's a few relevant lines of code from the API header file:

```
/* Utility functions to set ndpi malloc/free/print wrappers */

void set_ndpi_flow_malloc(void* (*__ndpi_flow_malloc)(size_t size));

void set_ndpi_flow_free(void (*__ndpi_flow_free)(void *ptr));
```

Consider the `set_ndpi_flow_malloc()` function. Elsewhere in the source code, there is a `struct nDPI_flow_info` defined, and I see that struct used everywhere in the code. So I assume `set_ndpi_flow_malloc()` is to allocate one of these structs on the heap, populate it with some information maybe, and return the pointer.

But I don't understand the arguments into this function. If I had to guess, I'd say that `set_ndpi_flow_malloc()` accepts a pointer to another function, called `__ndpi_flow_malloc()`, and that function takes a `size_t` integer as an argument. Turns out, there's this function prototype elsewhere in the API header file:

```
void * ndpi_flow_malloc(size_t size);
```

That's ***kind of*** the function I need: I need `__ndpi_flow_malloc()` (two underline characters on the front of the name) What do those double underlines mean?

Another question... if `set_ndpi_flow_malloc()` is a custom `malloc()` function, shouldn't it return a pointer to the allocated memory?

Another question... How would I actually write this in my code? Like this...?

```
struct nDPI_flow_info* myFlow;

set_ndpi_flow_malloc( (void*) &ndpi_flow_malloc( sizeof( struct nDPI_flow_info )) );

// ...use the struct...

set_ndpi_flow_free( &ndpi_flow_free* myFlow ) );
```

That can't be right. I don't understand how the second line returns the pointer and assigns it to variable `myFlow`.

Any advice or criticism is wildly appreciated. Thanks!

FULL DISCLOSURE :: I have also posted this question [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/iv88ez/custom_malloc_function_what_does_this_syntax_mean/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `set_ndpi_flow_malloc` doesn't actually do the allocation but allows you to set the function that does.  It's argument is a pointer to a function that takes a `size_t` and returns a `void *`, and the name of the *argument* is `__ndpi_flow_malloc`.

The same goes for `set_ndpi_flow_free`.  It tells the library which function to use as its custom free function.

Most likely, `ndpi_flow_malloc` is the default custom allocator.  So if this is the one you want to use you would do the following to set it as the custom allocation function:

```
set_ndpi_flow_malloc(ndpi_flow_malloc);
```

Then assuming there is a similar default free function called `ndpi_flow_free`, you would do this to set it as the custom free function:

```
set_ndpi_flow_free(ndpi_flow_free);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with this API, but based on what you've posted here it must allocate memory internally to perform some operations, and it allows you to specify which allocator/deallocator it should use to do that - it can either use vanilla `malloc` and `free` to allocate and deallocate memory, or you can pass a custom allocator/deallocator that uses a different allocation scheme or is instrumented for logging/debugging or whatever.

To make this easier to read, I'm going to rename things.  Basically pretend I've done

```
#define SNFM set_ndpi_flow_malloc
#define NFM  __ndpi_flow_malloc
```

That leaves us with

```
void SNFM(void *(*NFM)(size_t size));
```

which is read as

```
     SNFM                               -- SNFM
     SNFM(                         )    -- is a function taking
     SNFM(        NFM              )    --   parameter NFM
     SNFM(      (*NFM)             )    --   is a pointer to
     SNFM(      (*NFM)(           ))    --     a function taking
     SNFM(      (*NFM)(       size))    --       parameter size
     SNFM(      (*NFM)(size_t size))    --       is a size_t
     SNFM(     *(*NFM)(size_t size))    --     returning a pointer to
     SNFM(void *(*NFM)(size_t size))    --       void
void SNFM(void *(*NFM)(size_t size));   -- returning void
```

So basically, the argument to `set_ndpi_flow_malloc` is a pointer to a function that takes a `size_t` and returns a pointer to `void` - i.e., `malloc` or a function with the same signature that does the same thing:

```
set_ndpi_flow_malloc( malloc );
```

or

```
void *my_malloc( size_t size )
{
  ...
}
...
set_ndpi_flow_malloc( my_malloc );
```

This function doesn't allocate memory; instead, it's how you specify which allocator to use when the library needs to allocate memory internally.  `set_ndpi_flow_free` does the same thing with the deallocator - you can either use the vanilla `free` from the standard library, or pass a custom deallocator:

```
set_ndpi_flow_free( free );
```

or

```
void my_free( void *ptr )
{
  ...
}
...
set_ndpi_flow_free( my_free );
```

Comment: Wow, thanks John, this is incredibly detailed and informative.  You make perfect sense.  So I think for my purposes, I don't need set_ndpi_flow_free() but the simpler ndpi_flow_malloc() function, which I'm guessing the authors intended as the default selection.  Thank you!